# Unable to evaluation expressions from Eclipse Display View while debugging decompiled code in PaxExam integration test

Tags: java, eclipse, pax-exam

I'm debugging a PaxExam integration test in Eclipse.  I'm currently stepping through the code for a class and method that I don't yet have the source for.  When it hits the breakpoint, it says "Source not found" (with the "Edit Source Lookup Path" button), but when I visit the class file I know it's using, it's able to decompile it (using jd-eclipse).

(Note that running paxexam tests actually forks a process, so debugging them requires setting the "-Xdebug" parameters in the run configuration of the test class, and then using a "Remote Java Application" configuration to connect to it.)

While stepping through most of the code, I can enter expressions in the Display view, even with available completions, and display values and execute methods.

When it hits the breakpoint in the decompiled class (showing "Source not found" in the editor view), I can see the local and instance variables in the Variables pane.  I can then switch to the view of the decompiled class and use the stack trace info to see what line I'm on.

At this point, if I try to enter any expression in the Display View and display it (even just "this"), it says:

> Evaluation failed...To perform an evaluation, an expression must be
>   compiled in the context of a Java project's build path. The current
>   execution context is not associated with a Java project in the
>   workspace.

I'm trying to get access to the source code for this class, but I would think I wouldn't need to go to that point.  Is there a reasonable workaround for this situation?